# Reinstatement of Expired SFDC Certification

Tags: certification

I had Admin 201 / Sales Cloud / Service cloud consultant certifications, however my Admin 201 certificate expired recently. If I retake the Admin 201 certification, would my other 2 certifications (Sales / Service Cloud Consultant) get reinstated ?

Comment: you can log a case to salesforce